# Would you be interested in a Tribes: Ascend play night or SMITE beta giveaway from Hi-Rez Studios?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I was recently contacted by some folks at [Hi-Rez Studios](http://www.hirezstudios.com/hirezwp/), and they'd like to hold a [Tribes: Ascend](https://account.hirezstudios.com/tribesascend/) play night for the Arqade community and possibly follow it with a [SMITE](https://account.hirezstudios.com/smitegame/) closed beta key giveaway. I think working with Hi-Rez could be really fun, and just wanted to gauge interest here before I go ahead with planning out specifics.

Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Count me in!!!!! :)

Comment: I think this is a great idea, but I probably won't be able to play.  I was invited to the Tribes beta before it even released and I haven't been able to get it all downloaded yet.  My internet sucks.

Comment: Maybe I'm paranoid, but what's in it for them?

Comment: This sounds like fun, actually.

Comment: To anyone interested, I will say this: SMITE is a ton of fun. =3

Comment: @RonanForman Since we have such an active community, it's a great opportunity for them to get more people playing their games and excited about the SMITE release.

Comment: I'm in, as long as no one rages at me for enjoying my Plasma Gun.

Comment: A good friend of mine is in a management position at Hi-Rez and I actually attended the Tribes: Ascend launch party, so I can vouch firsthand - those guys are awesome.

Comment: I'd love it! Ascend is a lot of fun!

Comment: I'm following up with this; is this still in the works?

Answer (score 10):

First of all, of course I'm interested, why wouldn't I be.

Secondly, normally when the community play games together, we play at 6 UTC, as this is evening in Europe and afternoon in America, so this is the best time to play on weekends.

And finally, I *am* recording when we play and sticking it on our YouTube channel, that's final.

Comment: Awesome, I will keep these things in mind when planning it out with them :-)

Comment: Haha, I also record when we play (And I am not passed out in bed still :D)

Comment: Arqade has a youtube channel?

Comment: @Alok It's a community channel, http://youtube.com/arqadecommunity/

Comment: I'd think that if they don't want SMITE beta footage released, we could make the idea of recording the play sessions a little less "final".

Comment: @Sterno I was referring to the Tribes: Ascend pay night, of course I need to check with the devs about footage before posting anything from a closed beta.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to make sure!

Comment: I'll make sure to bring it up with them to see if it's ok.